# appspot xmpp talk with jabber.org

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

when i connect to gtalk, i able to talk with my bot in appspot. but when i login to jabber.org, i unable to talk with my bot? anything i need to configure?

testetefsdf @ appspot.com

p/s: the bot exist in my jabber.org roster and appear online thou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove this test when you want to chat with jabber user:

```
if (xmpp.getPresence(jid).isAvailable())
```

getPresence() works just for Gtalk user (i'm sure for [python API](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/functions.html), not for the JAVA one).

Anyway, paste your snippet if you can.

Comment: The configuration you describe is necessary for XMPP to work at all - App Engine can't magically find an XMPP handler without any configuration just because the message is coming from gmail.

Comment: Are you sure?Configuration is for message receiveing.http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html

Comment: Yup. i did added both configuration . Like i mentioned it did work perfectly when i login using gtalk and communicate with appspot. but when i log in jabber.org and communicate with appspot. it doesn't work